# Big Decorative Quotes

Tags: formatting, quoting, decorations

I want to make some definition in my thesis very clear, by putting it in its own line, with stylish, decorative (or whatever you call it) quotes. How can I do that in Latex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider to put your definition into a theorem-like environment. Here's an example using the `thmtools` package (with `ntheorem` as backend):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ntheorem}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\declaretheoremstyle[headfont=\scshape,bodyfont=\itshape,numberwithin=section]{mystyle}
\declaretheorem[style=mystyle]{definition}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\section{foo}

\blindtext

\begin{definition}
\blindtext
\end{definition}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry for being late, I got busy with other stuff. I am trying this, but I am getting this error on the link containing the `definetheoremstyle' command: Undefined control sequence! Any idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: The command name is `\declaretheoremstyle`.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, that's how I wrote it in the code but it was a mistake in my comment. Any idea why could this be caused?!

Comment: Does my example compile for you as-is? If not, try to update your TeX distribution.

Comment: Just tried it. Nope, it doesn't! Just in case you are wondering, I do have the full latex installed on an Ubuntu system, so I don't think it is a package problem (although I believe LaTeX should have mentioned this if it is a package problem).

Comment: Add `\listfiles` at the *very* start of my example, compile and check the log file. `ntheorem.sty` should be version `2011/02/16 1.31`; `thmtools.sty` should be `2010/08/09 v50`.

Comment: This is what I got: ***ntheorem: 2005/07/07 (1.25), thmtools: 2008/06/22 (v0.1beeta6)***. That is weird! I fully installed latex few months ago, so I would expect it to install the latex! How can I update them?!

Comment: It seems that the TeX installation shipped with Ubuntu is outdated. You should browse tex.sx for questions about Ubuntu (and, if necessary, ask a new question). I can't provide advice - I'm a Windows/MiKTeX user.

Comment: OK, using this http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14925/updating-tex-on-linux , I installed the latest update, and could compile your example. However, one problem is that I see "DEFINITION 1", which is not suitable for my thesis, because it is not kind of mathematical/logical book. Is there anyway to remove this?!

Comment: Replace `headfont=\scshape` with e.g. `headfont=\bfseries`.