# Fresh install texlive 2012 @ Ubuntu 12.04: tlmgr nowhere to be found

Tags: texlive, ubuntu

I know this subject has come up quite a few times so far (with different distro's of texlive). See for instance:

[Missing tlmgr texlive 2012](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68986/missing-tlmgr-texlive-2012)
[tlmgr: TeX Live 2011 is frozen forever](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57698/tlmgr-tex-live-2011-is-frozen-forever)
[Texlive installation is missing tlmgr, how to fix?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7609/texlive-installation-is-missing-tlmgr-how-to-fix)
http://the-praise-of-insects.blogspot.com/2011/08/tlmgr-not-available-for-ubuntu.html
http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=260451

None of them provided a solution that worked for me. The last link implies that the Ubuntu developers decided not to include tlmgr in the texlive distribution.

I installed texlive afresh via the following instructions: https://askubuntu.com/questions/160676/problems-installing-tex-live-2012-on-12-04

My texlive distro apparently lives here: `$ whereis texlive: /usr/share/texlive`

Any clue where to find tlmgr or how to activate it without reinstalling the texlive distribution all over again?

Comment: The Debian/Ubuntu provided TeX Live doesn't have `tlmgr` and will never have it. The only way to get it is to install the "vanilla" TeX Live from http://tug.org/texlive

Comment: Meaning there's no other solution then to install everything allover again? Hope there's an easier solution, as my connection here is very bad and it took me two full days to install everything... Also: what's the reason it's not included and never will be?

Comment: The reason is that Debian doesn't allow any other package manager than its own. Sorry for the problem with the connection; DVD with TeX Live are available from TeX Users groups and one may be near you.

Comment: You can of course install packages manually if you'd rather not install TeX Live all over again; if you are comfortable with the commandline, it is not particularly difficult.  See [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/73017/8528) for a fuller list of your options.  (The manual option will be useful too if you have limited bandwidth capabilities, since most packages are quite small: it is only when you add them all up that a TeX system becomes quite large.)

Comment: My commandline skills are pretty basic unfortunately. Could not extrapolate/deduct the right commands for solely installing tlmgr from your link. Is tlmgr such a complex script/program to install separately?

Comment: @grrrbytes -- You will never be able to 'install' `tlmgr` on its own: it is part of a TeX Live installation.  If you install from Debian/Ubuntu repositories, you will *never* have `tlmgr`.  I was just trying to suggest that you don't necessarily need to have it.  Many people manage to function just fine without having the most current versions of *TeX packages available, or by simply updating manually the packages they depend on (which is what I do; but regular visitors on this site tend to be the sort of people who want/need the cutting edge `tlmgr` affords them).

Comment: Guess you're right and is not having tlmgr not such a big deal. Actually, so far I always succeeded to work with tex without it. Just seemed to be a very convenient tool to have at hand that could spare you time, scratching my head and effort.

Comment: @grrrbytes -- absolutely.  I'm sure it is very useful to have.  I just prefer the convenience of a TeX system that is fully integrated with all the other programs on my computer (e.g., `emacs`), so I can't be bothered to trick my system into thinking all the dependencies are satisfied every time I do/install something where it expects the Debian version of TeX Live to be installed.  Plus most of the packages I need are updated at most once or twice a year, so it is not difficult to keep up to date.

Comment: @grrrbytes As both Debian maintainer of TeX Live and author of tlmgr, I would say that a normal user, i.e., not developer of (La)TeX/etc packages, nor one that plays with the latest font developments (esp otf math fonts), it is better on Debian/Ubuntu to stay with the native packages instead of installing your own copy. Especially if you don't know exactely about basic sysadmin tasks (PATH search priority, permissions etc), since if you don't know it is bound to create problems.

Comment: @grrrbytes Furthermore, if you are using Debian testing or sid (and if it exists something similar in Ubuntu), then after release of wheezy I plan to do monthly updates of the texlive packages based on the current tlnet status. Thus even Debian people would come - with a short delay - to latest packages.

Comment: I deleted my answer because it was not really an answer to the question. I'll transfer here the commands necessary to install TeXLive 2012 in Ubuntu 12.04, the "right" way: `sudo apt-add-repository ppa:texlive-backports/ppa; 
sudo apt-get update; 
sudo apt-get install texlive; 
sudo apt-get upgrade`

Comment: I quitted using debian version of texlive as it is badly old. just grab the texlive from ctan and use it. at the end do this: chown -R yourname:yourname yourtexfolder . That's all you need for tlmgr to work properly

Comment: @norbert Can you turn your comments into an answer? Perhaps adding that with the Debian provided TeX Live one *cannot* have `tlmgr`.

Answer (score 20):

As both Debian maintainer of TeX Live and author of tlmgr, I would like to state *my* personal ideas about it:

First, with the Debian native packages of TeX Live there will be in foreseeable time no tlmgr available. Even if it will be available, then only for managing TEXMFHOME or TEXMFLOCAL (for the sysadmin) (by using the user mode patches for tlmgr which are badly outdated at the moment).

On the other hand, it might not be necessary to have tlmgr available. Package installation, removal and configuration is done by the APT family (apt-get, aptitude and respective GUIs). Package search can be done with apt-cache search. That leads to the following suggestions:

For normal users, that are users who are not developers of (La)TeX/Font/etc packages, nor play with the latest font developments (esp. otf math fonts), for these users it is better on Debian/Ubuntu to stay with the native packages instead of installing your own copy. Especially if one does not know exactly about basic sysadmin tasks (PATH search priority, permissions etc), since if you don't know it is bound to create problems.

If you are developer, or have experience enough with both basic sysadmin tasks, using TeX Live upstream together with either a proper equivs package for texlive, or (disk space allowing) double installation.

Furthermore, if you are using Debian testing or sid (and if it exists something similar in Ubuntu), then after release of wheezy I plan to do monthly updates of the texlive packages based on the current tlnet status. Thus even Debian people would come - with a short delay - to latest packages.

Comment: I have texlive on my system (Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS) but the package "glossaries" was not installed. So I went to http://www.tug.org/texlive/pkginstall.html and then I was looking for `tlmgr` which is not available. I found this question and I followed your suggestion: `apt-cache search glossaries` answered me with `texlive-latex-extra - TeX Live: LaTeX supplementary packages` and so I installed `texlive-latex-extra` and I solved my problem.

Comment: I don't really want to turn this into a debate, but as a counter point, I am not a developer but I couldn't stand the fact that if I needed to install, say, `glossaries`, I had to install the 652 other packages I don't need from `texlive-latex-extra`. Apart from the old versions of the packages, it was the inefficiency and lack of control that lead me to install vanilla. And I couldn't be happier.

Comment: @jja I agree that the splitting is not optimal, but single package splits is even worse, as there would be about 2000+ new packages, which is not acceptable for Debian.

Comment: @norbert My impression is that `tlmgr` can update its list of packages independently, whereas if you use the native Debian/Ubuntu packages then you are limited to the ones that have been packaged for Debian. Is that correct? As a "normal user", right now on a Ubuntu 12.04 (virtual) machine (intentionally got an old version to test something), I'd like to install the package `kantlipsum`. I think with `tlmgr` I'd be able to just install it, whereas on Ubuntu even with `texlive-full` it's not available, so I'm out of luck. Is that correct?

Comment: @ShreevatsaR yes you are correct. The version in Ubuntu from 2012 is old, and thus many new packages are not contained. If you would install the newest 2016 TeX Live packages for Debian/Ubuntu you would get these new files. But this is not different to any other release package in Ubuntu, old releases of Ubuntu carry old versions of packages, a natural thing. OTOH if you use texlive upstream you can get daily updates. The question is, do you need that ;-) or is it upgraditis?

Comment: And one more comment, since wire some time (but after 2012), the Debian/Ubuntu packages ship tlmgr which is automatically set in user mode, so one can install updated packages via tlmgr.

Comment: @norbert I think as a "normal user" I may still sometimes want certain (not all!) CTAN packages that came into existence after I first installed my operating system. Especially if one avoids upgraditis (as you say) and does not needlessly upgrade one's OS, then one is more likely to get into this state. I also got confused because [at this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107017/why-does-tex-live-require-yearly-updates/107162#comment234155_107162) you said the texlive distribution is about the binaries (I imagine `pdftex`, `kpsewhich`etc.) rather than about the CTAN packages…

Comment: @norbert But if one can use tlmgr and install packages from CTAN as a user, I think that completely resolves the question most users have. Maybe this answer is worth updating?

Comment: Not from CTAN, but from CTAN's TeX Live repository. And it does not work seamlessly as newer TL releases, like 2016 change intervals.

Comment: But, i agree, this answer is outdated...

Answer (score 0):

For those that need it -

Sometimes tlmgr is useful because you've had to install some out of date or badly constructed package by manually copying files into the texmf tree and you need to get tex to sort out its paths etc.

Without tlmgr it can be pretty tricky so in ubuntu you're a bit screwed... however there is a work around: make your changes and then use synaptic to trigger the task tlmgr would have done by removing and reinstalling some part of the texlive distribution. This will trigger the tex install scripts to do this job for you.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: On those (hopefully) rare occasions when you do need to install manually, there are step-by-step instructions at http://latex.silmaril.ie/formattinginformation/addons.html#pkginst (the rest of the document needs updating, but I updated this section just now).