# AMS-TeX with TeXworks

Tags: texworks

I downloaded MiKTeX and got TeXworks. A document in TeXworks can be typeset with several alternatives: LaTeXmk, pdfTeX, pdfLaTeX, pdfLaTeX + MakeIndex + BibTeX, XeTeX, XeLaTeX, XeLaTeX + MakeIndex + BibTeX, ConTeXt (LuaTeX), ConTeXt (pdfTeX), ConTeXt (XeTeX), BibTeX, MakeIndex.

But I miss AMS-TeX, and this is what I need. I have a ten-year-old preprint written in AMS-TeX which I need to update and send to a journal for publishing, but I no longer work at a university and I don't have access to the TeX facilities I used to have. All I could do was to download MiKTeX to my home computer (with Windows).

So I wonder: is there any possibility for me to get AMS-TeX to work within any of the alternatives above? And is the command file `amsppt.sty` available somewhere and possible to use, with some of the above alternatives?

Maybe AMS-TeX today is considered obsolete, but that is what I once learned. I never learned LaTeX despite that it quickly became standard, since it used to be possible also to use AMS-TeX. Anyway, my preprint has 100+ pages, and I don't want to rewrite it completely with LaTeX or something else. I hope this won't be necessary.

Comment: MiKTeX sports an `amstex` package; if you didn't install it, do. Then adding a typesetting engine to TeXworks is rather easy: it's very similar to the procedure outlined for `arara` in [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/98795/4427); just use `amstex` instead (and no `verbose`)

Answer (score 10):

Here is a step by step description.

1. Make sure the `amstex` package is installed in MiKTeX
2. Open TeXworks and choose the "Preferences" menu

   [image]
3. Go to the "Typesetting" tab and this window will appear; click on the "+" button in the lower half

   [image]
4. Fill the window as follows

   [image]

   In order to add the lines in the "Arguments" field, click on the "+" button.
5. Click OK in this window and in the Preferences window.
6. Choose "amstex" from the drop down menu

   [image]
7. Click the "Typeset" button (the green one).
8. Enjoy AMS-TeX in flamboyant PDF format.

Here's the final picture

[image]

Comment: A minor note: Windows/Linux the preferences is found under the Edit menu.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thanks, I'm surely not familiar with the first platform you mention. `;-)`

Comment: After some trouble, it works! Thank you very much, egreg!