# TeXworks not writing .log or .aux files

Tags: texworks

Yesterday (Sep. 1, 2016) I ran all of the automatic updates for my MiKTeX. Since then, my TeXworks has not been writing .log or .aux files, at least not in the same directory as my .tex file or anywhere that I can think to look. Naturally this a problem since I search these files for warnings, missing character messages, multiply-defined labels, etc. Is there anything I can do to try to fix this problem? I'm using TeXworks Version 0.6.1 (MiKTeX 2.9) [r.3614278, 5/1/2016 4:43 AM], and my computer is Windows 7.

Even a file as simple as

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\section{Test}\label{sec1}
Reference to section \ref{sec1}.
Reference to section \ref{sec2}.
\end{document}
```

produces, in its directory, only a .pdf file and a .synctex.gz file. Oddly, the `\ref{sec1}` command prints correctly as "1". The `\ref{sec2}` command prints as "??", obviously, but since I have no .log file I have no way of confirming that the paper has undefined references.

EDIT: I'm also set up to run normal LaTeX on a .tex file via DVIWindo, and DVIWindo seems to have "seen" all the appropriate MiKTeX updates I made; the updated files are being used, and the .aux and .log files are still being written as normal.

Comment: After using TeXworks with pleasure for several years, there were minor bugs that made me switch to TeXstudio eventually.

Comment: Have you tried running a search over your whole computer for *.log and sorting by date to see if it's putting them somewhere wierd?  If the compilation is slow (and a deliberate `\hanghere` should help with that unless you have scrollmode automatically set) leaving the search window open should show where it puts the log even if it's deleting it at the end of the run.

Comment: Check the profile settings in texworks. Probably you have a --clean option somewhere.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer: Thanks. Where should I look for the profile settings?

Comment: Somewhere in the texworks settings.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer: Thanks again, but I couldn't even find the settings folder. I'm guessing there are too many possibilities about where it could be?

Comment: I meant the settings *menu* of texworks.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer: Sorry, but in my TeXworks, all I see is the Edit -> Preferences menu, which doesn't seem to have anything appropriate. I also see Help -> Settings and Resources, but that just creates a window listing some other directories. Am I missing something?

Comment: Well my texworks is in german. After I got an english version: Edit->preferences, tab "typesetting".

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer: Actually, on that tab the only helpful thing I saw was "Hide console output:", which I set to "Never". That let me see the most recent .log file at the bottom of the window showing my .tex file, along with an "Errors, warnings, badboxes" tab that seems helpful. I'd still like to have my TeXworks not delete .aux, .log, or any other kind of file automatically.

Comment: We like to keep answers separate from questions, so you should write a separate answer instead of editing your answer into the question. Self-answers are perfectly admissible, and a well-written answer may earn you additional reputation.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, I just now (Sep. 9, 2016) followed the instructions in the answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113776/ams-tex-with-texworks) to find the "--clean" option and remove it. It was under pdfLaTeX+MakeIndex+BibTeX. Now my TeXworks is writing all the files it should. If this is enough, thanks for your help.