# ConTeXt with TeXworks

Tags: context, texworks

I just downloaded a recent distribution for `ConTeXt`. I also have `TeXworks` installed on my Windows laptop. Can anyone give me a step-by-step guide on how to set up the `TeXworks` editor to compile `ConTeXt` files?

Comment: Edit, Preferences, Typesetting, Processing tools already has ConTeXt to choose from. Or did you mean how to set up parameters (if any)?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113776/ams-tex-with-texworks has screen images (related question).

Comment: Does the wiki help? https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Installation

Comment: I never used TeXworks, but there is also [this page](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/TeXworks) to look at.

Comment: Maybe (1) Load a simple doument  (e.g.`\starttext  foo \stoptext` ) (2) Select the right engine in the menu at the right of the green triangle, e.g.: `ConTeXt (pdfTeX)` (3) Push the green triable.      If the button is not longer a green triangle, you selected the wrong compiler or your document is wrong.

Comment: @Cicada Yes, got it up and running thanks to that post. Thanks so much!

Comment: @mickep Yes, I looked at that page. In hindsight, it makes sense, but at the time, it was hard to tell what they were saying.

Comment: @Fran The problem was with the menu. I couldn't select the option to compile with ConTeXt and I didn't know how to specify a compiler. All fixed now. Thanks for your help!