# Process with arara do not generate PDF file & .aux &

Tags: windows, texworks, arara

I don't know why, but after installing JDK, arara seems to work truly.
But it doesn't generate any file. (Like PDF)
 this massage show:

[image]

What should I do?

```
% ‎arara‎: ‎pdflatex
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
Hello world.
\end{document}
```

Comment: did you give arara the file as in a command line `arara myfile.tex` ? It looks like you just ran `arara` with no arguments and it output the help text

Comment: Can you explain how I Can give arara the file?

Comment: if your file is called `myfile` on the command line type `arara myfile.tex`  if you run commands from the editor it depends on which editor you use and how you configure it. Basically exactly the same as a command such as `pdflatex` you need to tell it which file to use. How, without arara, would you execute `pdflatex myfile.tex` ?

Comment: And I think you have to give compiling directions in the `.tex` file, e.g. `% arara: pdflatex` at the beginning of the file.

Comment: I use texwork and I dont want to generate pdf file with cmd (Windows) .  So what should I DO?

Comment: configurartion instructions http://uweziegenhagen.de/?p=2928

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98790/how-to-use-arara-with-texworks

Comment: When I type "arara myfile.tex" on the command line I get this massage: "I didn't find any directives in 'asd.tex', and so didn't do
anything. Is that what you really wanted?"