# nonewpage option in imakeidx prevents me from using an .ist file

Tags: indexing, imakeidx, makeindex

I want to have my index (using `imakeidx`) at the beginning of my document, so for that I need to use the `nonewpage` option. I also want to right-align the page numbers in the index with dots in-between, so I created the .ist file

```
delim_0 "\\dotfill"
```

However, the `nonewpage` option prevents the .ist file from running properly. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nonewpage]{imakeidx} % taking out nonewpage lets the ist file put dots in    
\makeindex[options=-s debugging]

\begin{document}
Some text
\index{refer}
\index{Howsit}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

Can I achieve both an index at the front of the document, as well as having dots leading up to right-aligned page numbers?

Comment: If you use `nonewpage` you have to run `makeindex` manually.

Comment: @egreg I'm using pdfLaTeX+MakeIndex+BibTeX to compile the MWE. Taking out `nonewpage` puts the dots in without running the `makeindex` separately.

Comment: That's clear. You need to run `makeindex -s debugging <filename>` in the second step: when you run `makeindex` manually it knows nothing about the options given to `\makeindex`.

Comment: @egreg I don't know what you mean. Do you mean putting `makeindex -s debugging` on the second line of the .ist file? I also named the .tex file debugging.

Comment: No, the `-s debugging` bit should go on the command line you call `makeindex` with.

Comment: I opened the command prompt and did that: https://pastebin.com/1RV4Xbdy
I then tried compiling the document, but there was no difference.

Comment: You have to run `pdflatex` again.

Comment: I restarted the command prompt and put the file name in after the first `debugging` (the file name is also debugging). It then worked. It's the first time I'm doing this, so thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the option `nonewpage` it's impossible for `imakeidx` to call automatically `makeindex`, because the index file has to be closed before the last page is shipped out and entries in it would be lost.

Assuming your file is named `ahorn.tex`, you have to run

```
pdflatex ahorn
makeindex -s debugging ahorn
pdflatex ahorn
```

(maybe with other calls in between, for instance `bibtex`). How you pass the option to `makeindex` depends on how you do the run and the front-end you use.

If you are able to run Arara (see [How to use arara with TeXworks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98790/)), you can do

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: makeindex: { style: debugging }
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nonewpage]{imakeidx} % taking out nonewpage lets the ist file put dots in
\makeindex

\begin{document}
Some text
\index{refer}
\index{Howsit}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

and the single call

```
arara ahorn
```

will take care of everything.

[image]

Comment: I haven't yet used arara, but I've now used the command prompt in this way for the first time.