# Bold and colon in imakeidx

Tags: indexing, imakeidx

I use `imakeidx` which is great except for the fact that it is not clear enough what numbers are page numbers and what the rest.

Here is the example:

[image]

It is hard to distinguish that 88 is page number and 1 Kön 8, 12 index entry.

Is there a way to make all index entries bold by default and add colon after index entry? Like this:

**1 Kön 8, 12:** 88

I presume that this can be done with renewing \index command but I am not sure how.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}%
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[nonewpage]{imakeidx}% MULTIPLE INDICES
\indexsetup{level=\section*,toclevel=section,headers={Stellenregister}{\indexname}}%
\makeindex[name=band1-bibelstellen,title=Bibelstellen, intoc, options= -s untitled.ist]
\makeindex[name=band1-themen,title=Themen, intoc, options= -s untitled.ist]
\makeindex[name=band1-personen,title=Personen, intoc, options= -s untitled.ist]
\begin{document}
\blindtext
\blindtext\index[band1-bibelstellen]{1 Kön 8,12}
\blindtext\index[band1-themen]{Epiph.!haer.!8, 16}
\blindtext\index[band1-personen]{Arius!Anhänger!Eusebius}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Alex. Al.!ep. encycl.!1, 12}
\printindex[band1-bibelstellen]
\printindex[band1-themen]
\printindex[band1-personen]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please provide a [compilable document](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) called MWE.

Comment: Sorry I knew I forgot something. I edited my question now to include MWE. Thanks!

Comment: This isn't related to `imakeidx` itself -- you would get the same 'error' with `makeidx` -- it's caused by the way of information is given to `\index` or using a different `.ist` file for the index

Comment: I don't get any error. The question is about customising index entries and I use`imakeidx` so that is why I mentioned it.

Comment: @eklisiarh: That's why I wrote 'error' ;-)

Comment: OK got it now, sorry. Anyway, do you know a way to do this? I tried modifying example from this answer but it didn't work: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/267366/renewcommand-index

Comment: Can you please add the contents of `untitled.ist`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok after 12 hours of trying, based on the solution suggested by Christian Hupfer (thank you!) and this page: https://linux.die.net/man/1/makeindex here is the solution:

Add this code to your `.ist` file

```
item_0 "\n\\bfseries\\item "
item_1 "\n\\bfseries\\item "
item_2 "\n\\bfseries\\item "
delim_0 ":\\quad\\normalfont "
delim_1 ":\\quad\\normalfont "
delim_2 ":\\quad\\normalfont "
```

and `-c` to the `options` parameter.

Also you have to remove `nonewpage` parameter because this doesnt work with `.ist`.

The solution for that is to add:

```
\let\clearpage\relax
\let\cleardoublepage\relax
```

in front of:

```
\printindex
```

That creates error `\clearpage undefined` so if you want you can put `\batchmode` in front of `\printindex` or you can use this solution: [nonewpage option in imakeidx prevents me from using an .ist file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/390930/nonewpage-option-in-imakeidx-prevents-me-from-using-an-ist-file)

Comment: `nonewpage` is nonsensical with the `scrbook` class.