# Package PAGELAYOUT, 'cannot access shell'

Tags: layout, shell-escape

While running the package-supplied *.tex samples for **pagelayout.cls**, I am getting error messages. That alone is odd, because I would expect those examples to be rock-solid. The errors claim that the compiler didn't have **shell** access, and so it aborted the run.

I have tried the same files in **TexWorks** and in **Kile**....same errors reported. And neither of them suggest a way of resolving the problem.

Any ideas about why this error is occurring?

PS--would someone with a reputation >300 please add the "pagelayout" tag (tag zfpagelayout exists, but it is not the same package)

*******************Update, reply to Friedmann ************
ImageMagick version is 6.9.11.60. I cannot find a way to upgrade to 7 or higher. there are no higher versions in the Linux_Mint synaptic repository. I tried updating via `sudo apt update` but that failed.

I ran `xelatex example-borders-and-shadows.tex` as you suggested and I got this error message at the end of several dozen lines:

```
/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-xetex.def
runpopen command not allowed: extractbb

! I can't find file `"|extractbb --version"'.
<to be read again> 
                   \scan_stop: 
l.72     \l__sys_internal_tl
                            
(Press Enter to retry, or Control-D to exit)
Please type another input file name:
```

Comment: The package `pagelayouts` needs shell-escape to run as can be seen in `/scripts/pagelayoutapi` and the errors present in `pagelayout.cls` (if you CTRL+F and type "shell" you can see the error messages/commands). The way around it is to enable `shell-escape`, if you have a full installation of TeXlive (where TeXworks comes from) then you can use [`arara`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/arara) to do `shell-escape` like `% arara: pdflatex: {shell: yes, options: [-halt-on-error]}`, you need to setup the path to `arara` in TeXworks like this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/98795/273733

Comment: I am not sure how to do it in native LaTeX or with `latexmk` as I use `arara` exclusively, hopefully someone else can help with that (note: the `-halt-on-error` option is so that if errors cause the programme to end without compiling it doesn't leave `pdflatex.exe` hanging and not being able to delete `aux` files, if that happens you need to kill the process manually)

Comment: I wouldn't run examples with --shell-escape without first inspecting them carefully. `--shell-escape` gives them access to your computer.

Comment: Ulrike: Are you suggesting that the examples included by the creator of pagelayout.cls (Mssr. F. Bartels) would actually have malicous content? Is the _shell script_ actually capable of behaving maliciously?

Comment: I set up arara, and got further (that is, fewer error messages). But I still got an error message _execcv forbidden_

Comment: Discovered that you need to add the pagelayout api file to the "personal" texmf.cnf file. This file was essentially empty, except for a "readme" header. So this has been updated, but I cannot run "sudo texhash". If I run  texhash (no sudo), I get replies that the files are not writeable. If I try sudo texhash, I get an error saying that texhash command does not exist . Very strange, because I do remember running sudo texhash in the past, and it worked. Any ideas?

Comment: @Birdman Nobody is suggesting that the creators of whatever packages are trying to hack your computer. But consider this: 1) As (La)TeX software is mostly open source, virtually everybody can edit code or upload files which may end up on your computer as examples. 2) Even if nobody intentionally wants to harm you, errors in the code can still affect your computer. Therefore, you should avoid using `--shell-escape` with files that you do not fully know the contents of.

Answer (score 0):

Troubleshooting shell access with pagelayout class:

1. Make sure Inkscape version 1.0 or higher is installed by running `inkscape --version`.
2. Make sure ImageMagick version 7.0 or higher is installed by running `magick --version`.
3. Make sure the pagelayoutapi script is installed by running `pagelayoutapi --version`.
4. Try to build the example example-borders-and-shadows.tex by running `xelatex example-borders-and-shadows.tex`. If an error occurs type H  for help and follow the instructions.

If you still run into errors, please let me know:

- the exact error
- your TeX distribution
- how you installed the package

Note: after updating the texmf.cnf you do not need to run `sudo texhash`. This command is only required when manually installing the package.

Comment: Inkscape is OK. Pagelayoutapi is OK. ImageMagick version is 6.9.11.60 (see edits in the original question). Xelatex run fails (see edits in the original question). Thanks, Friedemann, for your response...very much appreciated.

Comment: Oh, I had installed the pagelayout.cls package using the tlmgr --gui. That was on 24th Feb, after nuke-and-pave and reinstall of TexLive 2022.  Today, tlmgr does NOT work anymore. See my latest question on this forum, added today.

Comment: Is there a particular Path setting that pagelayout.cls (or, indeed, LaTeX) uses to locate Imagemagick, Inkscape when those supporting programs are called?

Comment: It seems like I have resolved problems with shell access now.

Comment: But, issues with "inkscape not found" and "imagemagick not found" are still present even though they are in my $PATH. I checked $PATH from the directory of TeXLive 2022 and they are both there. These error messages are definitely generated by the code 'pagelayout.cls' (for examples, at lines 3660, 3661), but I've been unable to discover where 'pagelayout.cls' expects to find these accessory programs. And with particular reference to Imagemagick, which of the individual routines of I.M. does it require?

Comment: I fixed a bug with version 1.0.4 where the "inkscape not found" error was shown when Inkscape was installed, but not ImageMagick 7. Even if ImageMagick 7 is not installed, now you should be able to build the file `example-borders-and-shadows.tex`. ImageMagick is called with the command `magick` when using image optimization or the preflight mode.

Comment: PS: I recognized that the installation of ImageMagick 7 on Linux is not always possible with the default package manager. So I am considering to support ImageMagick 6 too in the future.

Comment: Hello, Friedemann: You say 'ImageMagick is called with the command `magick'. But when I run 'whereis magick' and 'magick --version' from the terminal, 'magick' is not found. So...what file, or script...etc...is the command 'magick' supposed to point to?

Comment: Friedemann: I have updated pagelayout.cls on my computer and, as you predicted, the file 'example-borders-and-shadows.tex' now functions properly. Meanwhile, Imagemagick isn't working (for example, compile of 'example-graphic.tex' fails).

Comment: I took the plunge: downloaded Imagemagick v7, updated the dependencies, installed etc and now I have a working copy of v7. Pagelayout.cls seems to work seamlessly now, no faults with the file ```example-graphic.tex``` now!  I just need to resolve a hiccup with Imagemagick v7 linkage within the 'desktop menu' now. Thanks for all the help; now I can get down to using the pagelayout.cls and generating REAL questions about the vagaries of that class's application to the work at hand!