# BibTex does not work and MiKTeX PATH issue

Tags: bibtex, paths

I am a total newbie to this. I have recently installed MiKTeX on Windows 10. I work with a template given from my university so the code should be OK, but there is a problem probably with BibTex. After compiling the code to pdf, there are no citations (for example the code *The steps are described in \citet[str.29]{Blabla}* is compiled to *The steps are described in* **?***, str. 29.* Maybe there could be a problem with PATH? Because anytime when I open MiKTeX console, there is a PATH issue. During installation I did not change any directory (as it was recommended) but still there is an issue, that "This directory is not in the search path for executables or it is at a wrong position in the path...". I kinda do not understand the problem. Which certain directory needs to be added? I have written there the directory where miktex-console.exe and other apps are located. After confirming this with Fix it button, it appears that it is ok but next time I run MIKTeX console there is PATH issue again.

Comment: are you actually calling bibtex? If yes how? Is there a .blg-file in your folder? What is its contents? (As a side remark: don't trust too much university templates, the majority are unmaintained and bad).

Comment: I hope so. There is a comment (loosely translated) "...and it search a corresponding book in a file literatura.bib". And this file is in my folder. It contains for example @BOOK{Blabla,
  title = {xx},
  publisher = {xx},
  year = {2007},
  author = {yyy.},
  address = {yy},
  isbn = {000}
}  
 And this template should work as it is official for our theses :D And which exact line is "calling a bibtex"? Sorry for dumb questions, I am confused with all those formats etc.

Comment: well I would say you don't know what "calling bibtex" means. Which editor do you use?

Comment: I use TexWorks.

Comment: then use the dropdown menu beside the green arrow, select bibtex and then click on the green arrow again.

Comment: And then, after running BibTeX, be sure to run (pdf)LaTeX twice more.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not solve this. I get the same results. By the way I used in the dropdown menu pdfLaTeX+MakeIndex+BibTex previously.

Comment: then find the blg-file. That is the log-file from bibtex and will hopefully contain some clue.

Comment: Well, I feel like an idiot - there is no blg-file. However when I tried to run pdfLaTeX, then BibTex two or three times and then pdfLaTeX again and it suddenly worked....

Comment: As an aside, I use TeXworks too and run files using `arara`, for example this at the top of the file: `% arara: lualatex: {options: [-halt-on-error]} % arara: biber % arara: lualatex: {options: [-halt-on-error]}` compiles it with one click on TeXworks, if you are interested then look at this answer by one of the creators: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/98795/273733