# Is upgrading feature available for TeXLive 2013

Tags: installing, texlive

I just found out that it is not possible to upgrade TeXLive from 2012 to 2013 versions so you'll have to do a new install of TeXLive 2013.

Does anyone know if the upgrading feature will be available for TeXLive 2013? That is, will it be possible to upgrade TL 2013 to TL 2014? Otherwise it'll be a pain installing it and uninstalling it everytime I need a new package in the old version.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107017/why-does-tex-live-require-yearly-updates

Comment: FYI: you shouldn't actually have to uninstall TeX Live 2012, as the  directory structure changed a bit and they're kept in different directories (`/usr/local/texlive/2013` vs. `/usr/local/texlive/2012`). Unless you're concerned about storage space on your computer, you should be able to keep both versions on your machine.

Comment: No, there's no upgrading procedure, due to the fact that the tree structure has been modified. There's no need to uninstall older distributions. On one machine of mine I have all TeX Live editions since the 2007 releases. Actually “upgrading” has never been recommended.