# How to fix biblatex warning about deprecated option

Tags: biblatex, texlive, biber, latexmk

When I compile my document using `latexmk main.tex` I get the following 
warning

> Package biblatex Warning: 'firstinits' option is deprecated, use 'giveninits' instead.

How do I get rid of this? I've installed and updated all packages in TeX Live 2015 using [this guide](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95373/38817).

---

**main.tex**

```
\documentclass[a4paper, hidelinks]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[numbered, atend]{bookmark}

\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=ieee,
    urldate=iso8601,
    sorting=nty
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{main.bib}

\begin{document}

\printbibliography{}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you write the `firstinits` option in your preamble, or does it come with a package?

Comment: I haven't written the `firstinits` option, I think it come with a package

Comment: Then probably you'll have to wait till the package is updates. Do you know which packages are loaded in relation with `biblatex`?

Comment: I guess `biber`

Comment: `biber` is not a package.

Comment: What are the options you load with `biblatex`?

Comment: Updated question

Comment: `biblatex-ieee` has not yet been updated. You could report the issue to the package author. But basically, the best thing is to do is to report it and then wait for it to be updated. It is only a warning, after all.

Comment: The `biblatex-ieee` version on [CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-ieee) dates from 2016-04-16 and uses `giveninits` and not the deprecated `firstinits`. According to [this site](https://www.tug.org/texlive/) TeX live 2015 was frozen on or around 2016-04-04 which means that this updated is not included there. You can just ignore the warning (it's a warning after all) and wait for TeX live 2016 where the updated version will be included, or you can update the package manually if you absolutely must.

Comment: @moewe Okay that explains it. Do you have a guide for how to manually update the package?

Answer (score 7):

*TeX live 2016 has been released now, so you should consider upgrading to the 2016 version to get the newest package versions.*

The [`biblatex-ieee` on CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-ieee) is from 2016-04-16 and uses the new name `giveninits` instead of the old name `firstinits`.

Since the TeX live 2015 freeze was around 2016-04-04 that version has not made it to TeX live 2015 and you are stuck with the older version that uses the old names.

Note that in your case you only get a warning and the option still takes effect, as far as I can see the rest of the package works absolutely fine with `biblatex` 3.3. So it is not essential to do an update now. If you still want to do one, please refer to [Update a package after TeX live freeze?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/117518/35864) and [Updating packages while TeX Live is frozen](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/174176/35864).