# Updates via TexLive Utility

Tags: update

I have noticed that there has not been any updates to the distribution for a few weeks. I am wondering if this is as a result of there actually BEING no updates, or if there is something wrong with TexLive Utility? I have done several searches and have come up empty-handed.

Thanks,
DM

Comment: Please give us deatils! (OS, distribution, stb...)

Comment: @TomSolid TeX Live Utility is a Mac OS X application supplied as part of MacTeX.

Comment: See for example http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/174176/updating-packages-while-tex-live-is-frozen, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117518/update-a-package-after-tex-live-freeze, _etc._

Answer (score 6):

There will never again be updates to TeX Live 2015 or earlier. Soon, TeX Live 2016 will be available and that version will then get updates, so you will get updates if you install the new version.

There is an annual period during which the previous version of TeX Live is frozen and the new one is tested. Eventually, the new one is released and becomes the current version. At that point, users can install the new edition of TeX Live. That new version's `tlmgr` (the utility underlying TeX Live Utility) can then get updates for the new installation until it, in its turn, is frozen forever the following year.

Thus the cycle continues unto somewhere in the vicinity of eternity.

Comment: Of course I did know that, just didn't realise we were in update lockdown. Thanks for the heads-up, vote to close.

Comment: If you run `tlmgr` directly with `update`, it returns a message which tells you. I guess TLU doesn't pass this on?

Comment: @cfr, TLU only knows that the listing failed, and it could be for any number of reasons; parsing tlmgr error messages is too fragile, and Karl and I never worked out a scheme to number exit codes. I give more detailed error messages when the local and remote versions don't match, but that's because I do the work of checking the remote version.