# Why the packages are not up to date in tex live package manager?

Tags: texlive

I found the ctex package ([this link](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/ctex?lang=en)) is updated to version 2.0.2 in 2015/5/16. So I open my tex live 2014 package manager expecting to update to the latest `ctex` package, but there is only 1.02d, and it tells me that no updates available. What is wrong?
[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> TeX Live 2014 is frozen forever and will no longer be updated.  This
>   happens in preparation for a new release.

This happened at [April 10](https://www.tug.org/texlive/). The new TeX Live 2015 should be available from June 12.

[Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/107162/8368) is an explanation why TeX Live is frozen every year prior to a new release.

You can manually install `ctex` by:

1. Download it from [CTAN](http://mirrors.ctan.org/install/language/chinese/ctex.tds.zip)
2. Unpack it to your `texmf-local` folder, which should be `%SystemDrive%\texlive\texmf-local` on Windows.
3. Run texhash to register the package.

Comment: Oh, my god. I just swtiched to tex live from Miktex for a few weeks. Now I have to uninstall it and install the newest 2015 version a few days later? So you mean every year, I have to reinstall a newer version? Why? I just need the new package, not a new tex live.

Comment: @user15964 You don't have to reinstall, and with recent TeX Live versions updating from one to another has been possible.

Comment: @JosephWright how? I didn't see such option. Could you please show me the way?

Comment: @JosephWright, even on Windows?

Comment: @daleif Not according to [this](https://www.tug.org/texlive/upgrade.html)