# tlmgr update now require wget

Tags: mactex, updating, tlmgr

I've tried to install beamer on mac using `tlmgr`, but it asked me to update `tlmgr`, so I did it. Now when I try to install a package it complains saying that `wget` is not installed (and it is not, I'm on mac, but it was fine before the update). Any suggestion to fix this mess? (Other than installing `wget`)

Here is the output:

```
$ tlmgr install beamer
tlmgr: package repository 
http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/systems/texlive/tlnet (not verified: gnupg not available)
tlmgr itself needs to be updated.
Please do this via either
  tlmgr update --self
or by getting the latest updater for Unix-ish systems:
  http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/update-tlmgr-latest.sh
and/or Windows systems:
  http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/update-tlmgr-latest.exe
Then continue with other updates as usual.

tlmgr: Terminating; please see warning above!
$ tlmgr update --self
tlmgr: package repository 
http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/systems/texlive/tlnet (not verified: gnupg not available)
tlmgr: saving backups to /usr/local/texlive/2016basic/tlpkg/backups
[1/2, ??:??/??:??] update: texlive.infra [197k] (41476 -> 44462) ... done
[2/2, 00:01/00:02] update: texlive.infra.x86_64-darwin [277k] (40402 -> 43815) ... done
tlmgr: package log updated: /usr/local/texlive/2016basic/texmf-var/web2c/tlmgr.log
running mktexlsr ...
done running mktexlsr.
$ tlmgr install beamer
/Library/TeX/texbin/tlmgr: Initialization failed (in setup_unix_one):
/Library/TeX/texbin/tlmgr: could not find a usable wget.
/Library/TeX/texbin/tlmgr: Please install wget and try again.
/Library/TeX/texbin/tlmgr: Initialization failed (in setup_unix_one):
/Library/TeX/texbin/tlmgr: could not find a usable xzdec.
/Library/TeX/texbin/tlmgr: Please install xzdec and try again.
tlmgr: Couldn't set up the necessary programs.
Installation of packages is not supported.
Please report to texlive@tug.org.
Use of uninitialized value $r in split at /Library/TeX/texbin/tlmgr line 3980.
tlmgr: Cannot find main repository, you have to tag one as main!
```

Comment: Not a direct answer, but updating using the TeX Live Utility GUI installed with MacTeX works without a hitch. Also, `wget` is a fallback to what it usually does.

Comment: Furthermore, you're trying to install 2016 packages using the current year repository. This won't work.

Comment: I'm using BasicTeX

Comment: @AlanMunn `Furthermore, you're trying to install 2016 packages using the current year repository. This won't work`. Could you explain? I'm not an expert at all. Thank you.

Comment: TeX Live is updated each year, and the default repository is set to the current year. So you can't update from the default repository once the newest year's distribution is out. There are two solutions: install the current year (I would recommend the full distribution and not BasicTeX, see [Do I HAVE to re-install all self-installed packages when TeXLive/MacTeX update yearly?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/318343/) for reasons) or tell `tlmgr` to use a historic repository.  See [How to install a package from an older version of TeXLive?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25089/) .

Comment: On yearly TeX Live updates, see [Why does TeX Live "require" yearly updates?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/107017/2693).

Comment: You could download and run the 2016 `update-tlmgr-latest.sh`, which *might* restore your TL 2016 version of `tlmgr`. It looks like you partially overwrote tlmgr by doing an infrastructure update from TL 2017, as @AlanMunn noted. ftp://ftp.tug.org/historic/systems/texlive/2016/tlnet-final/update-tlmgr-latest.sh

Comment: Thanks everyone. Just two more things: if I install the 2017 version, do I have to manually uninstall the previous version or the installer takes care of that too? Is it possible that previously written tex document no more compile with the new version?

Comment: You have installed MacTeX and then used the command line. I am not sure whether this works, since texbin is a link to the real directory, and thus the update via `tlmgr update --self` seems to have broken something. This is indicated by the fact that neither wget nor xz is found which should be. I only guess here, but the `tlmgr-update-latest` did install into texbin but not into the real installation directory, which broken the setup. I don't have a Mac to actually try it, but this is what I read from your log.