# Why can not upgrade texlive2016 to texlive2017 on windows

Tags: texlive

I have `texlive 2016` installed on my windows OS, to use `texlive 2017` you need to download it (over then 2.5GO), I think this is a tedious operation every time you  want to pass from an old texlive to a recent one.

My question is is there a posibility just to upgrade `texlive 2016` to `texlive 2017`without removing, downloading, and installinig  the entire texlive?

Comment: no it is the same every year, install a new texlive.

Comment: No way..... :-(

Comment: No one forces you to upgrade, if you would rather stay with texlive 2016 that is fine.

Comment: All too often the structure of TeX Live changes from year to year so there is no simple one to one structure to update.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to remove the previous year TeX live installation to install the next one.

Nevertheless, upgrade is not possible. [as detailed here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/107162/89949), which I invite you to look at, basically it's stated that upgrades could be kind of risky, this is way there is not a supported way to do so and so the "safe way" is to do a fresh install.

Think of the possibility of corruption of the packages if something goes wrong, the hours invested in upgrading scripts and the pain of a possible rollback. The pain is removed, and all of those hours are invested somewhere else in the LaTeX development area.