# how to update TeXLive on a Mac?

Tags: installing, mac, mactex

While updating it just says your version of TeX Live Utility in 2016 needs to change the repository to 2017. And I was also told to change repository when I worked in Windows but I need to update on a  Mac.

Comment: You just need to download the [new MacTeX image](http://www.tug.org/mactex/downloading.html). See [Why does TeX Live require yearly updates](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/107017/2693).

Comment: Need to install freshly

Comment: Yes, you can't update from 2016 -> 2017 without a new install.

Comment: @AlanMunn What you say is almost true!