# Is there a bug with the `lipsum` package in the last update of MikTeX?

Tags: miktex, lipsum

I have the full version of `MikTeX` updated today.
When testing the code on page 396 of the following `tcolorbox` manual 4.14, it is requested to install the `lipsum` package which is normally included in `MikTeX`.
 I installed it, but the compilation still fails.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,landscape]{article}
\usepackage[noheadfoot,margin=0pt]{geometry}
\usepackage[skins,raster,magazine]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newenvironment{leaflet}[1][]{%
\begin{tcolorbox}[nobeforeafter,empty,colback=white,
sharp corners,size=minimal,left=10mm,right=10mm,top=10mm,bottom=10mm,
width=\textwidth/3,
breakable,
break at=\textheight,
height fixed for=all,
reset box array,
store to box array,#1]}
{\end{tcolorbox}%
\begin{tcbitemize}[raster columns=3,raster equal skip=0pt,blankest]
\tcbitem\consumeboxarray{5}
\tcbitem\consumeboxarray{6}
\tcbitem\consumeboxarray{1}
\tcbitem\consumeboxarray{2}
\tcbitem\consumeboxarray{3}
\tcbitem\consumeboxarray{4}
\end{tcbitemize}%
}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{leaflet}[underlay={\node[above=5mm,font=\footnotesize]
at (frame.south) {- \arabic{tcbbreakpart} -};}]
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Basilica_5.png}
\begin{center}
\bfseries\LARGE Example
\end{center}
\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Main Part A}
\lipsum[2-8]
\section{Main Part B}
\lipsum[9-15]
\section{Conclusion}
\lipsum[16-18]
\end{leaflet}
\end{document}
```

[image: install]

the log file indicates this:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (MiKTeX 2.9.6880 64-bit) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2018.11.24)  24 NOV 2018 07:22
entering extended mode
**./test.tex
(test.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-04-01> patch level 5
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size10.clo"
File: size10.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count80
\c@section=\count81
\c@subsection=\count82
\c@subsubsection=\count83
\c@paragraph=\count84
\c@subparagraph=\count85
\c@figure=\count86
\c@table=\count87
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\geometry\geometry.sty"
Package: geometry 2018/04/16 v5.8 Page Geometry

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\keyval.sty"
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks14
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifpdf.sty"
Package: ifpdf 2018/09/07 v3.3 Provides the ifpdf switch
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifvtex.sty"
Package: ifvtex 2016/05/16 v1.6 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
Package ifvtex Info: VTeX not detected.
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\ifxetex\ifxetex.sty"
Package: ifxetex 2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
)
\Gm@cnth=\count88
\Gm@cntv=\count89
\c@Gm@tempcnt=\count90
\Gm@bindingoffset=\dimen103
\Gm@wd@mp=\dimen104
\Gm@odd@mp=\dimen105
\Gm@even@mp=\dimen106
\Gm@layoutwidth=\dimen107
\Gm@layoutheight=\dimen108
\Gm@layouthoffset=\dimen109
\Gm@layoutvoffset=\dimen110
\Gm@dimlist=\toks15

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\geometry\geometry.cfg"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\tcolorbox\tcolorbox.sty"
Package: tcolorbox 2018/07/26 version 4.14 text color boxes

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pgf\basiclayer\pgf.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pgf\utilities\pgfrcs.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgfutil-common.tex"
\pgfutil@everybye=\toks16
\pgfutil@tempdima=\dimen111
\pgfutil@tempdimb=\dimen112

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgfutil-common-lists.te
x")) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgfutil-latex.def"
\pgfutil@abb=\box26
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\ms\everyshi.sty"
Package: everyshi 2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgfrcs.code.tex"
Package: pgfrcs 2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.31)
))
Package: pgf 2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.15)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcore.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphicx.sty"
Package: graphicx 2017/06/01 v1.1a Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphics.sty"
Package: graphics 2017/06/25 v1.2c Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\trig.sty"
Package: trig 2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics-cfg\graphics.cfg"
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 99.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics-def\pdftex.def"
File: pdftex.def 2018/01/08 v1.0l Graphics/color driver for pdftex
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen113
\Gin@req@width=\dimen114
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pgf\systemlayer\pgfsys.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\systemlayer\pgfsys.code.tex"
Package: pgfsys 2014/07/09 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.48)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgfkeys.code.tex"
\pgfkeys@pathtoks=\toks17
\pgfkeys@temptoks=\toks18

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgfkeysfiltered.code.te
x"
\pgfkeys@tmptoks=\toks19
))
\pgf@x=\dimen115
\pgf@y=\dimen116
\pgf@xa=\dimen117
\pgf@ya=\dimen118
\pgf@xb=\dimen119
\pgf@yb=\dimen120
\pgf@xc=\dimen121
\pgf@yc=\dimen122
\w@pgf@writea=\write3
\r@pgf@reada=\read1
\c@pgf@counta=\count91
\c@pgf@countb=\count92
\c@pgf@countc=\count93
\c@pgf@countd=\count94
\t@pgf@toka=\toks20
\t@pgf@tokb=\toks21
\t@pgf@tokc=\toks22
 ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\systemlayer\pgf.cfg"
File: pgf.cfg 2008/05/14  (rcs-revision 1.7)
)
Driver file for pgf: pgfsys-pdftex.def

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\systemlayer\pgfsys-pdftex.def"
File: pgfsys-pdftex.def 2014/10/11  (rcs-revision 1.35)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\systemlayer\pgfsys-common-pdf.def
"
File: pgfsys-common-pdf.def 2013/10/10  (rcs-revision 1.13)
)))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\systemlayer\pgfsyssoftpath.code.t
ex"
File: pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex 2013/09/09  (rcs-revision 1.9)
\pgfsyssoftpath@smallbuffer@items=\count95
\pgfsyssoftpath@bigbuffer@items=\count96
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\systemlayer\pgfsysprotocol.code.t
ex"
File: pgfsysprotocol.code.tex 2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
)) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\xcolor\xcolor.sty"
Package: xcolor 2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics-cfg\color.cfg"
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 225.
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1348.
Package xcolor Info: Model `hsb' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1352.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1364.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1366.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1367.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1368.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1369.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1370.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1371.
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcore.code.tex"
Package: pgfcore 2010/04/11 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.7)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmath.code.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathcalc.code.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathutil.code.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathparser.code.tex"
\pgfmath@dimen=\dimen123
\pgfmath@count=\count97
\pgfmath@box=\box27
\pgfmath@toks=\toks23
\pgfmath@stack@operand=\toks24
\pgfmath@stack@operation=\toks25
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.code.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.basic.code.
tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.trigonometr
ic.code.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.random.code
.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.comparison.
code.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.base.code.t
ex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.round.code.
tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.misc.code.t
ex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.integerarit
hmetics.code.tex")))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfloat.code.tex"
\c@pgfmathroundto@lastzeros=\count98
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorepoints.code.tex
"
File: pgfcorepoints.code.tex 2013/10/07  (rcs-revision 1.27)
\pgf@picminx=\dimen124
\pgf@picmaxx=\dimen125
\pgf@picminy=\dimen126
\pgf@picmaxy=\dimen127
\pgf@pathminx=\dimen128
\pgf@pathmaxx=\dimen129
\pgf@pathminy=\dimen130
\pgf@pathmaxy=\dimen131
\pgf@xx=\dimen132
\pgf@xy=\dimen133
\pgf@yx=\dimen134
\pgf@yy=\dimen135
\pgf@zx=\dimen136
\pgf@zy=\dimen137
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorepathconstruct.c
ode.tex"
File: pgfcorepathconstruct.code.tex 2013/10/07  (rcs-revision 1.29)
\pgf@path@lastx=\dimen138
\pgf@path@lasty=\dimen139
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorepathusage.code.
tex"
File: pgfcorepathusage.code.tex 2014/11/02  (rcs-revision 1.24)
\pgf@shorten@end@additional=\dimen140
\pgf@shorten@start@additional=\dimen141
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorescopes.code.tex
"
File: pgfcorescopes.code.tex 2015/05/08  (rcs-revision 1.46)
\pgfpic=\box28
\pgf@hbox=\box29
\pgf@layerbox@main=\box30
\pgf@picture@serial@count=\count99
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcoregraphicstate.co
de.tex"
File: pgfcoregraphicstate.code.tex 2014/11/02  (rcs-revision 1.12)
\pgflinewidth=\dimen142
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcoretransformations
.code.tex"
File: pgfcoretransformations.code.tex 2015/08/07  (rcs-revision 1.20)
\pgf@pt@x=\dimen143
\pgf@pt@y=\dimen144
\pgf@pt@temp=\dimen145
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorequick.code.tex"
File: pgfcorequick.code.tex 2008/10/09  (rcs-revision 1.3)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcoreobjects.code.te
x"
File: pgfcoreobjects.code.tex 2006/10/11  (rcs-revision 1.2)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorepathprocessing.
code.tex"
File: pgfcorepathprocessing.code.tex 2013/09/09  (rcs-revision 1.9)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorearrows.code.tex
"
File: pgfcorearrows.code.tex 2015/05/14  (rcs-revision 1.43)
\pgfarrowsep=\dimen146
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcoreshade.code.tex"
File: pgfcoreshade.code.tex 2013/07/15  (rcs-revision 1.15)
\pgf@max=\dimen147
\pgf@sys@shading@range@num=\count100
) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcoreimage.code.te
x"
File: pgfcoreimage.code.tex 2013/07/15  (rcs-revision 1.18)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcoreexternal.code.t
ex"
File: pgfcoreexternal.code.tex 2014/07/09  (rcs-revision 1.21)
\pgfexternal@startupbox=\box31
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorelayers.code.tex
"
File: pgfcorelayers.code.tex 2013/07/18  (rcs-revision 1.7)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcoretransparency.co
de.tex"
File: pgfcoretransparency.code.tex 2013/09/30  (rcs-revision 1.5)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorepatterns.code.t
ex"
File: pgfcorepatterns.code.tex 2013/11/07  (rcs-revision 1.5)
)))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\modules\pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex"
File: pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex 2014/03/21  (rcs-revision 1.35)
\pgfnodeparttextbox=\box32
) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\modules\pgfmoduleplot.code.tex"
File: pgfmoduleplot.code.tex 2015/08/03  (rcs-revision 1.13)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pgf\compatibility\pgfcomp-version-0-65.
sty"
Package: pgfcomp-version-0-65 2007/07/03 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.7)
\pgf@nodesepstart=\dimen148
\pgf@nodesepend=\dimen149
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pgf\compatibility\pgfcomp-version-1-18.
sty"
Package: pgfcomp-version-1-18 2007/07/23 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.1)
)) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\tools\verbatim.sty"
Package: verbatim 2014/10/28 v1.5q LaTeX2e package for verbatim enhancements
\every@verbatim=\toks26
\verbatim@line=\toks27
\verbatim@in@stream=\read2
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\environ\environ.sty"
Package: environ 2014/05/04 v0.3 A new way to define environments

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\trimspaces\trimspaces.sty"
Package: trimspaces 2009/09/17 v1.1 Trim spaces around a token list
)
\@envbody=\toks28
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\etoolbox\etoolbox.sty"
Package: etoolbox 2018/08/19 v2.5f e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
\etb@tempcnta=\count101
)
\tcb@titlebox=\box33
\tcb@upperbox=\box34
\tcb@lowerbox=\box35
\tcb@phantombox=\box36
\c@tcbbreakpart=\count102
\c@tcblayer=\count103
\tcolorbox@number=\count104
\tcb@temp=\box37
\tcb@temp=\box38
\tcb@temp=\box39
\tcb@temp=\box40
\tcb@out=\write4
\tcb@record@out=\write5

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\tcolorbox\tcbskins.code.tex"
Library (tcolorbox): 'tcbskins.code.tex' version '4.14'
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pgf\frontendlayer\tikz.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pgf\utilities\pgffor.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pgf\utilities\pgfkeys.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgfkeys.code.tex"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pgf\math\pgfmath.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmath.code.tex"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgffor.code.tex"
Package: pgffor 2013/12/13 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.25)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmath.code.tex")
\pgffor@iter=\dimen150
\pgffor@skip=\dimen151
\pgffor@stack=\toks29
\pgffor@toks=\toks30
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\frontendlayer\tikz\tikz.code.tex"
Package: tikz 2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.151)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\libraries\pgflibraryplothandlers.
code.tex"
File: pgflibraryplothandlers.code.tex 2013/08/31 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.20)
\pgf@plot@mark@count=\count105
\pgfplotmarksize=\dimen152
)
\tikz@lastx=\dimen153
\tikz@lasty=\dimen154
\tikz@lastxsaved=\dimen155
\tikz@lastysaved=\dimen156
\tikzleveldistance=\dimen157
\tikzsiblingdistance=\dimen158
\tikz@figbox=\box41
\tikz@figbox@bg=\box42
\tikz@tempbox=\box43
\tikz@tempbox@bg=\box44
\tikztreelevel=\count106
\tikznumberofchildren=\count107
\tikznumberofcurrentchild=\count108
\tikz@fig@count=\count109

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\modules\pgfmodulematrix.code.tex"
File: pgfmodulematrix.code.tex 2013/09/17  (rcs-revision 1.8)
\pgfmatrixcurrentrow=\count110
\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn=\count111
\pgf@matrix@numberofcolumns=\count112
)
\tikz@expandcount=\count113

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\frontendlayer\tikz\libraries\tikz
librarytopaths.code.tex"
File: tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex 2008/06/17 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.2)
)))
\tcb@waterbox=\box45

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\tcolorbox\tcbskinsjigsaw.code.tex"
Library (tcolorbox): 'tcbskinsjigsaw.code.tex' version '4.14'
)) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\tcolorbox\tcbraster.code.tex"
Library (tcolorbox): 'tcbraster.code.tex' version '4.14'
\c@tcbrastercolumn=\count114
\c@tcbrasterrow=\count115
\c@tcbraster=\count116
) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\tcolorbox\tcbmagazine.code.tex"
Library (tcolorbox): 'tcbmagazine.code.tex' version '4.14'
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\tcolorbox\tcbbreakable.code.tex"
Library (tcolorbox): 'tcbbreakable.code.tex' version '4.14'
\tcb@testbox=\box46
\tcb@totalupperbox=\box47
\tcb@totallowerbox=\box48
)))

! LaTeX Error: File `lipsum.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name: 
! Emergency stop.
<read *>
```

Comment: Well then, just click the install button?

Comment: @Johannes_B I did it and the compilation failed.

Comment: Open the MikTeX console independently and check if the package is installed or not. If not, install it. Do you really need the package? You could replace it by `blindtext`.

Comment: Check in the console in the packages the properties of the package. If lipsum.sty is missing in the file list make a bug report in the MiKTeX packaging bug tracker. (Such errors can happen).

Comment: @Johannes_B I checked before asking the question and the latest version of `lipsum` dated November 20 is installed

Comment: @UlrikeFischer In the console it appears `lipsum.tmp+1` I posted here because the tags `MikTeX` are automatically relayed on the MikTeX website: https://miktex.org/

Comment: I don't know if Christian checks the generated list. The correct (and the fastest) way to report a packaging bug  is to add an issue.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer done : https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex-packaging/issues/68

Comment: The lipsum package on CTAN currently does not contain an .ins file. And running latex lipsum.dtx does not produce a .sty file (at least on my machine). That explains why the MiKTeX package is "empty".

Comment: @ChristianSchenk Can you make your comment an answer so that I can close the question as resolved?

Comment: As a result of your question a fix has been provided, Thanks to @moewew & patta42 (maintainer) You should be able to add the answer that it was fixed for you :-)

Comment: @KJO Okay, as soon as the update is available on `MikTeX`, if `Christian Shenck` (maintainer) doesn't turn his comment into a reply, I'll reply. Thank you :-)

Comment: Just got an update hence comment, but the revision seems out of sync with latest 2.1a 2018-11-24 so may need to wait a day or two?

Comment: @KJO Yes, all updates are done manually by distribution maintainers. Read: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/383459/the-updates-on-the-different-latex-distributions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to **moewew** who reported the error to **patta42** *(lipsum maintainer)* on GitHub 
[CTAN upload does not include ins file](https://github.com/patta42/lipsum/issues/11) a new file has been made available on CTAN.

Thanks to [Christian Schenk](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/461526/is-there-a-bug-with-the-lipsum-package-in-the-last-update-of-miktex#comment1160651_461526) ([MiKTeX](https://miktex.org/) maintainer) for explaining the nature of the problem in his comment:

> The lipsum package on CTAN currently does not contain an .ins file.
>   And running latex lipsum.dtx does not produce a .sty file (at least on
>   my machine). That explains why the MiKTeX package is "empty".

From now on, the `lipsum` package is functional again and this question can be closed.

Thanks to **patta42** for reacting so quickly.

Comment: Moewew may be our @moewe ?

Comment: I'm asking myself the same question!