# Ubuntu cannot find latex package

Tags: exercisebank

Though

> texlive-latex-extra

is already there, still Ubuntu 18.04 says the package

> exercisebank

is not found.

```
apt-cache search exercise
```

The above returns nothing.

How to solve the issue ?

Comment: According to https://ctan.org/ctan-ann/id/mailman.2959.1522660990.5100.ctan-ann@ctan.org `exercisebank` was uploaded to CTAN the first time on 2018-04-02. In particular that means it will be available in TeX live 2018 (I guess even from the start, but not in TeX live 2017). Bionic's `texlive-latex-extra` has version information `2017.20180305-2`, which means it is a TeX live 2017 system updated at 2018-03-05. At that point `exercisebank` was not yet available and hence is not included.

Comment: You can either install the package manually (and face possible version incompatibilities with dependencies) or you can get a vanilla TeX live 2018 from TUG https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1092/35864.

Comment: It might be useful for you to install `apt-file` then you can do `apt-file exercisebank.sty` and it will tell you which ubuntu package would provide this file. very useful to figure out stuff like this.

Comment: Hello! I'm the author of exercisebank, and you can find an updated version both on [github](https://github.com/Strauman/exercisebank) and on [CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/exercisebank) that you can use until you possibly update your TeXLive installation (or wait for Bionic's version to update). Awesome that you (evidently) use my package! Also, feel free to report any bugs and/or feature requests at the [github](https://github.com/Strauman/exercisebank) repo :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turning my comments into an answer

According to https://ctan.org/ctan-ann/id/mailman.2959.1522660990.5100.ctan-ann@ctan.org `exercisebank` was uploaded to CTAN for the first time on 2018-04-02. In particular that means it will be available in TeX live 2018 (I guess even from the start), but not in TeX live 2017, which was already [frozen](https://tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2018-March/041104.html) [at that point](https://tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2018-March/041108.html) (see [Why does TeX Live "require" yearly updates?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/107017/35864) for background on the yearly TeX live freeze).

[Bionic's `texlive-latex-extra`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/bionic/+package/texlive-latex-extra) has version information `2017.20180305-2`, which means it is from a TeX live 2017 system last updated at around 2018-03-05. At that point `exercisebank` was not yet available and hence is not included.

If you want the package, you can try to install it manually from [CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/exercisebank), see [How do I install an individual package on a Linux system?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/73016/35864). You may run into version incompatibilities with package dependencies, though, so I usually am not too fond of that.

The alternative is to get a vanilla TeX live from TUG and install that. Then you can install your favourite packages via `tlmgr` (or choose a full install that installs all available packages). See [How to install "vanilla" TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1092/35864). The current release version is TeX live 2018 (which is already frozen), and TeX live 2019 is expected to be released in a month or so.