# Encoding scheme `TU' unknown (fontawesome with moderncv)

Tags: pdftex, moderncv, fontawesome

When I try to enable fontawesome icons in moderncv, I get this error in the `pdflatex` log:

```
! LaTeX Error: Encoding scheme `TU' unknown.
```

A minimal example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}                                                                          
                                                                                                                     
\moderncvstyle{casual}                                                                                               
\moderncvcolor{blue}                                                                                                 
                                                                                                                     
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                                                                                          
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                                                                                             
\usepackage{lmodern}                                                                                                 
                                                                                                                     
\usepackage{babel}                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                     
\name{John}{Doe}                                                                                                
\title{C/C++ Development}                                                                                            
\phone[mobile]{+1~xxx-yyyy}                                                                                       
\email{john.doe@gmail.com}                                                                                    
\homepage{www.tractor.com}                                                                                      
                                                                                                                     
\social[linkedin]{johndoe}                                                                                      
\social[github]{john-doe}                                                                                       
\social[stackoverflow]{012345/johndoe}                                                                         
\social[orcid]{0000-0001-2345-6778}                                                                                  
\social[researchgate]{John-Doe}                                                                                 
\social[googlescholar]{ADFIE89AD}                                                                                 
                                                                                                                     
\moderncvicons{awesome}                                                                                              
                                                                                                                     
\renewcommand*{\bibliographyitemlabel}{[\arabic{enumiv}]}                                                            
                                                                                                                     
\begin{document}                                                                                                     

\makecvtitle                                                                                                         
                                                                                                                     
foo                          
                                                                                    
\end{document}
```

In `fontawesomebrands.fd` and `fontawesomepro.fd`  there are many references to `TU`, so it appears to be some kind of central element. But without any hint from `pdflatex`, and nothing in google searches, I don't have a way to figure out what's missing or configured wrong.

UPDATE: excerpts from the log file that look relevant to fontawesome (since there is no way to post an actual log file attachment):

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2021) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2023.3.13)  10 AUG 2023 12:33
entering extended mode                                                                                               
 restricted \write18 enabled.                                                                                        
 %&-line parsing enabled.                                                                                            
**minimal.tex                                                                                                        
(./minimal.tex                                                                                                       
LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 4                                                                                   
L3 programming layer <2021-05-07>                                                                                    
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/moderncv/moderncv.cls                                                       
Document Class: moderncv 2021/01/21 v2.1.0 modern curriculum vitae and letter document class                         
...                                                                                                                  
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontawesome5/fontawesome5.sty                                               
Package: fontawesome5 2020/03/24 v5.13.0 Font Awesome 5                                                              
                                                                                                                     
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/l3keys2e/l3keys2e.sty                                            
Package: l3keys2e 2021-05-07 LaTeX2e option processing using LaTeX3 keys                                             
)                                                                                                                    
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontawesome5/fontawesome5-generic-help                                      
er.sty                                                                                                               
Package: fontawesome5-generic-helper 2020/03/24 v5.13.0 non-uTeX helper for fon                                      
tawesome5                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                     
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontawesome5/fontawesome5-mapping.def)                                      
)) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/academicons/academicons.sty                                              
Package: academicons 2020/08/14 v1.9.0 Academicons Icons                                                             
))                                                                                                                   
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty                                                       
Package: hyperref 2021-02-27 v7.00k Hypertext links for LaTeX                                                        
...                                                                                                                  
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for U+fontawesomefree2 on i                                      
nput line 33.                                                                                                        
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontawesome5/ufontawesomefree2.fd)                                          
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/mt-cmr.cfg                                                        
File: mt-cmr.cfg 2013/05/19 v2.2 microtype config. file: Computer Modern Roman                                       
(RS)                                                                                                                 
)                                                                                                                    
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for TS1+lmr on input line 3                                      
3.                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                     
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/ts1lmr.fd                                                                
File: ts1lmr.fd 2015/05/01 v1.6.1 Font defs for Latin Modern                                                         
)                                                                                                                    
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for U+fontawesomefree1 on i                                      
nput line 33.                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                     
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontawesome5/ufontawesomefree1.fd)                                          
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for U+fontawesomebrands0 on                                      
 input line 33.                                                                                                      
                                                                                                                     
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontawesome5/ufontawesomebrands0.fd)                                        
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `U/fontawesomebrands0/solid/n' in size <10> not                                       
available                                                                                                            
(Font)              Font shape `U/fontawesomebrands0/regular/n' tried instead o                                      
n input line 33.                                                                                                     
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for U+fontawesomebrands1 on                                      
 input line 33.                                                                                                      
                                                                                                                     
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontawesome5/ufontawesomebrands1.fd)                                        
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `U/fontawesomebrands1/solid/n' in size <10> not                                       
available                                                                                                            
(Font)              Font shape `U/fontawesomebrands1/regular/n' tried instead o                                      
n input line 33.                                                                                                     
                                                                                                                     
                                                                                                                     
! LaTeX Error: Encoding scheme `TU' unknown.                                                                         
                                                                                                                     
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.                                                             
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.                                                                                
 ...                                                                                                                 
                                                                                                                     
l.33     \end{document}
```

Comment: TU is the default unicode encoding used in lualatex and xelatex, it is not usable in pdflatex

Comment: When making the switch from pdflatex to lualatex/xelatex, be sure to also delete (or comment out) the instructions `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` and `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`.

Comment: I get no error from pdflatex in texlive 2023 show the log of your test file

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I was not intending to use either lualatex or xelatex, I just want to use pdflatex. Is that possible with fontawesome icons in moderncv?

Comment: do not show only snippets from the log. You don't know what is important, and it makes it impossible to use diff to compare with our logs.

Comment: I get the error you show in texlive 2020 but not 2021, 2022, 2023 so the simplest thing to do would be to update your tex system it was clearly a bug that got fixed.

Comment: Trying to post the log file, I get: `Body is limited to 30000 characters; you entered 43718.`

Comment: It's texlive 2021: `This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2021)`. But ok, I'll update and see if anything changes.

Comment: Nothing changes after updating. It's still texlive 2021, and it still fails with the same error about 'TU' encoding.

Comment: Solved by upgrading to Fedora 38. It was a bug, and the fixed version will apparently never be available in the Fedora 36 packages (which will expire soon anyway).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message that `TU` is unknown indicates that you are trying to use a font package which only works with LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX in a pdfLaTeX document.

The font causing this issue is `academicons` which automatically gets loaded by `moderncv` up to version 2.1.0 when `\moderncvicons{awesome}` is selected.

In `moderncv` version 2.2.0 (released on 2021-07-28), `\moderncvicons{awesome}` has been changed to no longer automatically load `academicons` and therefore became compatible with pdfLaTeX.

So in order to solve this issue, you need to install a newer `moderncv` version. The latest version (v2.3.1) still got into TeX Live 2021, so you can do this either by updating to e.g. TeX Live 2023 or by installing package updates for your existing TeX Live 2021. When trying to update an existing installation, remember that since TeX Live 2022 has been released the default mirrors no longer contain packages for TeX Live 2021, so to update TeX Live 2021 you have to follow the instructions [for updating historic distributions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/683038/80496). That's assuming that you installed TeX Live manually. If you got it from some distribution package you need to follow the usual procedures to update your packages.

Comment: Thank you, I see the problem here. Both texlive and moderncv were installed using `dnf` on Fedora, which (after updating **today**) still gives me `\ProvidesClass{moderncv}[2021/01/21 v2.1.0 modern curriculum vitae and letter document class]`. So I'll have to find some workaround, or upgrade the entire install beyond Fedora 36.

Comment: Works perfect in Fedora 38, including other stuff that was broken like the `\born` command.

Comment: Semi off topic, but you are aware that Fedora 36 reached EOL about three months ago? I would strongly recommend updating it ASAP.

Comment: I'm often hesitant to update because things get broken. For example, after upgrading to Fedora 38 across my network, I am now unable to compile my main C++ project. Version 13.2 of GCC crashes with a segfault while instantiating a particularly complex template, and emits an error message indicating to file a report on redhat bugzilla. Nobody at redhat has responded to my report after 3 days.  It's taking me quite a while to work around the bug, and **it would not have happened** if I had chosen to keep dragging my feet about the upgrade.