# Why does [alldates=terse] cause an error with biblatex?

Tags: biblatex

I'm using [MacTex 2019](https://tug.org/mactex/) as my LaTeX environment. Everything seems to work properly except this thing. For some reason, the minimal example at the bottom gives the following error:

```
main.tex:23: Undefined control sequence.
\lbx@us@mkdaterangetrunc@short ...}}}}}\endngroup
```

The error is gone if I change the option `alldates` to something else than `terse` such as `long` or `short`.

**How could I make the `terse` option work as that is the format I'd like to use? Am I doing something wrong here?**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{ref.bib}
@online{foo,
  title={Foo},
  url={https://example.com},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[backend=biber, alldates=terse]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{ref.bib}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}

Introduction \cite{foo}.
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This issue was caused by a bug that was resolved in `biblatex` 3.13.
>
> Please update your TeX distribution to obtain the current versions of `biblatex` and Biber.

This is an embarrasing typo in `english.lbx` (`\endngroup` instead of `\endgroup`). The issue has already been fixed in the `dev` version of `biblatex` (https://github.com/plk/biblatex/commit/c33c966736762a6158830512f65f5a54c745952b), the fix is included in `biblatex` v3.13.

For the time being, you can patch the relevant macro (note that you have to do that in `\AtBeginDocument` or after `\begin{document}`, because the patch must come in after `english.lbx` is loaded).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, alldates=terse]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \patchcmd{\lbx@us@mkdaterangetrunc@short}
    {\endngroup}
    {\endgroup}
    {}{}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm! And yes, that `endngroup` indeed was the thing the error message was referring to. I wonder if there is an easy way to update a single package (on MacTex) when it is released?

Comment: @Paapaa If I'm not mistaken MacTeX is based on TeX live to some extent and gets package updates more or less like TeX live, which means that you can update your packages whenever you like (as long as you have the current TeX live and the repositories aren't frozen: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/107017/35864) and that you can expect to be able to get the update quite quickly after the new version of `biblatex` makes it to CTAN (no ETA as of yet). See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437/35864