# Why does the `date=terse` option to biblatex cause an extra space after the year in bibliography entries?

Tags: biblatex, spacing, biber, package-options, date

Compiling my MWE with the `date=terse` option to `biblatex` causes an extra space between the last digit in the year and the closing parenthesis. Commenting this option removes the extra space. How do I set the date to terse without causing this extra space?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber,%
            date=terse% comment to see difference.
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
@article{vanderwaals2010theories,
  author =       "Van der Waals, Johannes Diderik",
  title =        "Hey! Check Out These Forces!",
  year =         1873,
  journal =      "Studia Phisicum",
  publisher =    {Springer Nature},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}    
Science has invented many things, including~\cite{vanderwaals2010theories}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

If it matters, my environment is set up as follows:

```
bash-3.2$ pdflatex --version 
pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017)
kpathsea version 6.2.3
Copyright 2017 Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
Compiled with libpng 1.6.29; using libpng 1.6.29
Compiled with zlib 1.2.11; using zlib 1.2.11
Compiled with xpdf version 3.04
bash-3.2$ biber --version 
biber version: 2.10
```

Comment: Your TeX distribution is 2 years out of date, and this code doesn't produce the problem with the most recent version of `biblatex/biber` (3.13a/2.13).  Be aware that the versions of `biblatex` between your version and 3.13 had a bug that caused this code to produce an actual error, so you will need to update to the most recent version.

Comment: @AlanMunn, thank you, and that's great advice. For anyone else who follows, I believe AlanMunn means the bug of [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/499534/why-does-alldates-terse-cause-an-error-with-biblatex?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a bug in `biblatex` v3.10 (2017-12-19) that was resolved in v3.11 (2018-02-20). The current version is v3.13a (2019-08-31) and does not reproduce the issue.

The best way to get rid of this bug is to fully update your TeX distribution. Since you are using TeX live 2017 this means that you need to install the current TeX live 2019. See also [How do I update my TeX distribution?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437/35864), [Why does TeX Live "require" yearly updates?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/107017/35864).

In case you don't want to or can not update, the fix for this issue was committed in https://github.com/plk/biblatex/commit/1440a0c7f6e99fc664df2a9ff6bafb346801b63d and you can get a drop-in replacement for `english.lbx` with the fix at https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plk/biblatex/1440a0c7f6e99fc664df2a9ff6bafb346801b63d/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/english.lbx. It is probably easiest to simply download the file and put it in the same directory as your `.tex` file. *Remember to remove the file when you finally update your TeX distribution.*

Comment: Thank you @moewe. That worked wonderfully, and I will do so.