# Siunitx qty in TexStudio not working

Tags: siunitx, ubuntu

I try to use the `siunitx` package in TeXstudio, as far as I know `\si` is the old version and `\qty` is the new version.

I tried following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\qty[mode = text]{1.23}{J.mol^{-1}.K^{-1}} \\
\qty{.23e7}{\candela} \\
\qty[per-mode = symbol]{1.99}{\per\kilogram} \\
\qty[per-mode = fraction]{1,345}{\coulomb\per\mole}
\end{document}
```

The `\qty` is included in the auto completion, but the PDF is not created correctly.
[image]

I am using Ubuntu 20.04, I tried the code above in Overleaf and there it is working totally fine.

Can you help me find the problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's not your editor that's important, it's your TeX system (or rather your version of `siunitx`): add `\listfiles` to your input and report the `siunitx` version from the `File list` in the `.log`.

Comment: Ubuntu is known to be behind on their LaTeX updates, so you probably only have `siunitx` version 2, `\qty` is from version 3. Both v2 and v3 supports `\SI{...}{...}` though (in v3 `\SI = \qty`

Comment: Okay, yes it seems like I have only version 2. Is there a way to update the version?

Comment: If and how it is possible to update your TeX system depends on how it was installed. If you installed TeX live from the Ubuntu package sources via `apt`/`apt-get` you essentially have a frozen system that cannot be updated. In that case you may want to stick to the old `siunitx` v2 interface. You can, however, remove the `apt` TeX live and install a "vanilla" TeX live from TUG.org that can be updated (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1092/35864) - but it still needs to be upgraded once a year (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/107017/35864).